# Get all values greater than 'x'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following:

```
create table words (value varchar(10));
insert into words values('bbbbb');
insert into words values('ccccc');
```

If now I query `select * from words where value > 'b%';` I get:

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| bbbbb |
| ccccc |
+-------+
```

The question is: how can I get all tuples having the `value` column value greater than `b`?

I mean I wanna get all tuples having the value of the `value` column starting, according the alphabetic order, from c to z.

Comment: What do you mean by "greater than b"? `c` is greater than `b`...

Comment: you meant select * from words where value like 'b%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` operator compares string in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) see examples below:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' > 'b', 'b' > 'a', 'ab' > 'aaa', 'ab' > 'b';
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 'a' > 'b' | 'b' > 'a' | 'ab' > 'aaa' | 'ab' > 'b' |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
|         0 |         1 |            1 |          0 |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you are looking for patter matching you should use [like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) or regex. Check example:

[12.5.1 String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
mysql> SELECT  'bbbbb' like 'b%', 'cccc' like 'b%';
+-------------------+------------------+
| 'bbbbb' like 'b%' | 'cccc' like 'b%' |
+-------------------+------------------+
|                 1 |                0 |
+-------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[12.5.2 Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

```
mysql> SELECT 'bbbb' REGEXP 'b.*', 'cccc' REGEXP 'b.*';
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 'bbbb' REGEXP 'b.*' | 'cccc' REGEXP 'b.*' |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|                   1 |                   0 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
WHERE value  REGEXP '^[c-z]'
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be an effective solution (probably much more effective than a regexp):

```
WHERE left(value,1) > 'b' AND left(value,1) <= 'z'
```

Note this handles only lowercase letters, it may not work with uppercase letters, for them you may want to add more conditions